# VB.net how do I make Uppercase is the as as small caps

Tags: vb.net

I built my application and my application has a search textbox that searching for a specific text in string and the problem is I have to search the text in uppercase and small case, let's say the string = "Knife doppler" then if I want to find it I need to write in the search area in uppercase if I want to find any results, like this: "Knife" and if I search for "knife" I will get no results, how can I do that uppercase and small caps worth the same? I want to get a result if I search in uppercase or in small caps...

```
If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox3.Text
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        Dim lineCount As Integer = TextBox3.Lines.Count - 1
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For index As Integer = 0 To lineCount

            If TextBox3.Lines(index).IndexOf(TextBox2.Text) >= 0 Then
                counter += 1
                TextBox1.AppendText(TextBox3.Lines(index).ToString() + vbNewLine)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Show your code where you perform the actual search.

Comment: @hometoast updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find an overload that takes a [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) enum value that allows you to ignore the difference in text case.

```
If TextBox3.Lines(index).
   IndexOf(TextBox2.Text, 
   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
 .....
```